# How to pass props to child component from parent component and receive it in child component using react-redux

Tags: react-redux

My Parent component is like - Requestdetails component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import TopBarComponent from '../../common/TopBar/topBar'
export default class RequestDetailsComponent extends Component {
    showBreadcrumb: boolean;
    breadcrumbs: { title: string; navigate: string; state: boolean; }[];
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props)
        this.showBreadcrumb = true;
        this.breadcrumbs = [
            { title: 'Dashboard', navigate: 'dashboard', state: true },
            { title: 'Requests', navigate: 'requestList', state: true },
            { title: 'Request Details', navigate: '', state: false }]
    }
    render() {
        return (
           <div>
               <TopBarComponent showBreadcrumb={this.showBreadcrumb} breadcrumbs={this.breadcrumbs}/>
           </div>
        );
     }
}
```

Child component -- TopBar component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Breadcrumb, BreadcrumbItem } from 'carbon-components-react'

export default class TopBarComponent extends Component {
   showBreadcrumb:boolean;
   constructor(props:any){
       super(props);
       this.showBreadcrumb = props.showBreadcrumb
   }
   render() {
      let breadcrumbClass = 'dte-breadcrumbs dte-breadcrumbs--with-layout';

         if(this.showBreadcrumb){
             return (
                <div className={breadcrumbClass}>
                     <div className="dte-page-container">
                          <div className="container-fluid">
                               <Breadcrumb >
                                   <BreadcrumbItem>
                                         <a href="/#">Breadcrumb 1</a>
                                   </BreadcrumbItem>
                               </Breadcrumb>
                          </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
           );
       }
       return null;
     }
}
```

I want to pass 'showBreadcrumb' and 'breadcrumbs' array to topBar component from Requestdetails  component. but unable to do it in react-redux.

The above approach i used to follow in react but now i'm trying  this react-redux., but failed to pass.
Please advise how i can pass this.

Comment: Drew is correct as to "The redux way". But that doesn't strike me as what you're asking. A connected (or "smart") component shouldn't preclude you from using reacts "dumb" components as you would normally. I suspect if the above code fails its more likely that `this` hasn't been properly bound.

Comment: Then what you suggest,  how I can bind this properly and access the props in child. If I can pass props and access it in child component like the way we used to do in react,  it will be good for me. But currently it's not working. Please spread more light on it.

Comment: I would suggest you replicate the error in a code pen or minimal git repo as you haven't supplied enough information for someone to know why this isn't working for you.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have your redux store and provider setup and configured correctly, the way to connect UI components to your redux store, believe it or not, is with `react-redux`'s [`connect`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) HOC.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux'; // import the connect HOC
import { Breadcrumb, BreadcrumbItem } from "carbon-components-react";

class TopBarComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    let breadcrumbClass = "dte-breadcrumbs dte-breadcrumbs--with-layout";

    if (this.props.showBreadcrumb) {
      return (
        <div className={breadcrumbClass}>
          <div className="dte-page-container">
            <div className="container-fluid">
              <Breadcrumb>
                <BreadcrumbItem>
                  <a href="/#">Breadcrumb 1</a>
                </BreadcrumbItem>
              </Breadcrumb>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return null;
  }
}

// define a function that maps your redux state to props
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  breadcrumbs: state.breadcrumbs, // these should match how your reducers define your state shape
  showBreadcrumb: state.showBreadcrumb,
});

// export the connected component
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TopBarComponent);
```